# Can if statements be used within usestates?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a useState as follows:

```
const [Total, setTotal] = useState(props.location.state.data.price)
```

I would like to have it so if props.location.state.data.price is defined, it renders, but if undefined, then it returns 0.

I've tried nullish coalescing operators but it is not working. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: what error is it giving you when you use nullish coalescing and how would the props look if it were to be undefined

Comment: It's unusual to have props passed to state, unless `data.price` is meant to be some sort of default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either like this:

```js
const [Total, setTotal] = useState(props.location?.state?.data?.price ?? 0)
```

or like this:

```js
const [Total, setTotal] = useState(
  props.location &&
  props.location.state &&
  props.location.state.data &&
  props.location.state.data.price || 0
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably would want to also update `total` if `props.location.state.data.price` should change at some point, right? So I'd do that with an effect:

```
const [total, setTotal] = useState(0)  

useEffect(() => {
   if (!props.location?.state?.data?.price) {
       setTotal(0);
       return;
   }
   setTotal(props.location.state.data.price);
}, [props.location.state.data.price])
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it will always perform an initial commit to the DOM (or to the host-tree) with `0` and then it will schedule an update with the correct value. So, the user may see zero when there is an actual price.

Comment: Not to mention the fact that location could be `null` and then the code inside the effect would throw...

Comment: Agree, I've added "?" to the check in the answer. To your second point: Yes, that might happen, we'd need to check the full example to see if this is a problem